# Initialize a vector then copy all values intro a map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I want to store the values from a struct with two variabales of type char, intro a vector.

```
typedef struct SFoo
{
    char a[10];
    char b[10];
} FooTable;

std::vector<FooTable> vec_FooTable;
```

Then i want to acces those data through a map, i COPY the data from vector with a different method.

Let's assum that this mapx already have the data from the struct.

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, bool> mapx;
mapx map_foo;
```

I intialize the map like this

```
FooTable* p;
map_Foo[p->a] = true;
```

I acces the string stored like this

```
auto it = map_foo.begin();

while (it != map_foo.end())
{
    const std::string &r = it->first;
    it++;
}
```

I want to store all the variables from struct in a map, and acces them one by one.
If i initialize the map like this

```
FooTable* p;
map_Foo[p->a] = true;
map_Foo[p->b] = true;
```

The map will stor values like that:

```
Value a
value b
```

Note:  The values for a,b variable are taken from a mysql database from a table

How i can initialize the map so `a and b` will be unique?

I want to acces the struct values like this

```
= it->first->a;
= it->first->b;
```

Comment: `FooTable* p;` Here `p` is uninitialized, it is a *pointer* but it doesn't point to any data. When you use it you are getting *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I said that i intialize and copy the data in my own way.. using a packet. The packet send data from struct

Comment: This could be a failure on my part, but I cannot understand your problem well enough to answer or suggest ways to improve the question so that it can be answered.